# Reading camera with blob detection - TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I am trying to take an image from the video capture and run it through the blob detector and contour detection. I can get it to work from a png but really need to do the processing from the video capture if possible.

The line that causes the error is
*cnt_idx = np.squeeze(np.where(hier[0, :, 3] == b_idx))**

```
def camera(frame):
    frame_blurred = cv2.medianBlur(frame, 7)
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame_blurred, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    lower_green = np.array([0,49,255])
    upper_green = np.array([179,227,255])
    masked = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_green, upper_green)
    kernel = np.ones((3,3),np.uint8)
    opening = cv2.dilate(masked,kernel, iterations=2)

    #####################
    ### Circle Filter ###
    #####################
    height, width, depth = frame.shape
    mask = np.zeros((height,width),np.uint8)
    cv2.circle(mask, (int(round(width/2)), int(round(height/2))), 200, 1, -1)
    blob = cv2.bitwise_and(opening, opening, mask = mask)
    
      
    # keypoints = detector.detect(MaskedImage)
    # blob = cv2.drawKeypoints(MaskedImage, keypoints, np.array([]), (0,0,255), cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS)
    
    cv2.imshow("masked",blob)

# Read image; add an additional hole; find contours with hierarchy
    # blob = (frame, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    cv2.circle(blob, (380, 120), 25, 0, cv2.FILLED)
    contours, hier = cv2.findContours(blob(), cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    # Define sufficient enough colors for blobs
    colors = [(255, 0, 0), (0, 255, 0), (0, 0, 255)]

    # Get blob indices with respect to hierarchy
    blob_idx = np.squeeze(np.where(hier[0, :, 3] == -1))

    # Initialize blob images
    blob_imgs = []

    # Iterate all blobs
    k = 0
    for b_idx in np.nditer(blob_idx):

        # Add outer contour of blob to list
        blob_cnts = [contours[b_idx]]

        # Add inner contours of blob to list, if present
        **cnt_idx = np.squeeze(np.where(hier[0, :, 3] == b_idx))**
        if (cnt_idx.size > 0):
            blob_cnts.extend([contours[c_idx] for c_idx in np.nditer(cnt_idx)])

        # Generate blank BGR image with same size as input; draw contours
        img = np.zeros((blob.shape[0], blob.shape[1], 3), np.uint8)
        cv2.drawContours(img, blob_cnts, -1, colors[k], 2)
        blob_imgs.append(img)
```

Comment: Can you also attach the whole traceback? Along with Line number and error message ?

Answer (score 0):

Following piece of code seems to be your problem:

```
contours, hier = cv2.findContours(blob(), cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

change it to:

```
contours, hier = cv2.findContours(blob.copy(), cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

Remember that findContours works best on binary images.